# Vuetify data table - previous/next page is showing on the left side when items-per-page is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to completely hide the `items-per-page` choices from a table while keeping `next/previous` functionality untouched.

I can hide it by setting this props:

```
:footer-props="{
              'items-per-page-options':[10],
              'disable-items-per-page': true,
            }"
```

This[image] is great but now the `previous/next` functionality is on the left side of the table footer. I want to keep it on the right.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that has already been described in issues [#13751](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13751) and [#13678](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13678) of vuetify library. But there's still no "out of the box" solution.

You may fix your issue in several ways:

*First way*: Add **footer.prepend** slot into your `<v-data-table>` component with `<v-spacer/>` component:

```
<v-data-table 
  ...
  :footer-props="{
    'items-per-page-options':[10],
    'disable-items-per-page': true,
  }"
>
  <template #footer.prepend>
    <v-spacer/>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

*Second way*: If you don't need to support RTL, you may override one of the built-in CSS classes:

```
.v-application--is-ltr .v-data-footer__pagination {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

[There's a codepen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/zYdmzbE) where you may test both ways before applying it into your project.